# C# 4.0: Is there a way to check if application not exist in System.Diagnostics.Process.Start

Tags: c#-4.0, system.diagnostics

I want to open any file type by using the code below:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathFile);
```

Is there a way to check if system application not exist?

for example: pdf, the local machine has no acrobat reader.

I created a try catch, however I'm not satisfied with it, I want to imitate the behavior of windows in opening a file. It has an option of Searching the web / manual search.

```
try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pathFile);
            }
            catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
            {

                composite.ReadingError = ex.Message;
                Console.WriteLine("error");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use PInvoke ([FindExecutable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776419(VS.85).aspx) (shell32)):

- [How to use FindExecutable from C#](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/paytonbyrd/how-to-use-findexecutable-from-c-3324)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no association it should throw a `Win32Exception` that you could catch.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx in the exceptions section.